Keycloak Identity Provider Oauth2 only
Is it possible to add an Identity Provider to Keycloak (v24.x) that only supports Oauth2 not OIDC?
I know oauth2 is an authorization not authentication standard but apparently they don't.
It adds using a well-known URL but fails when selecting it on the login screen with
{"error": "invalid_scope",
 "error_description": "The requested 'openid' scope is not valid."}


OAuth2: Authorization Code, Implicit, Resource Owner Credentials,
Client Credentials, and Refresh Token. OpenID Connect introduces a new one, the Hybrid,
which is combining two particular OAuth2 grants into one single flow. Why you want to not OIDC?

@BenchVue I would be happy with OIDC but the specific provider I was asked to integrate does not support it.

As I know Keycloak no configuration to disable OIDC and OAuth2 option. Also ODIC do not hurt any OAuth2 flows.
